# How to retrieve JSON array values from a string with regex in Java

Tags: java, json, regex, pattern-matching, regex-group

I need to get values from a string with a JSON array using regex
String example:

```
[INFO][2022-11-11] Response body : 
{
   "values":[
      "abc123",
      "def456",
      "xyz789"
   ]
}
```

So I want to get the values: abc123, def456, xyz789

Please note I'm working with a string (actually it's a log output) so I'm not sure if I can use any  libraries for JSON parsing

I'm trying to use the following regex, but getting only the last array value xyz789:

```
"values"\s*:\s*\[(\s*"(\w+)"\s*,?)*]
```

My solution in Java

```java
String pattern = "\"values\"\\s*:\\s*\\[(\\s*\"(\\w+)\"\\s*,?)*]" ;

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(source());
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("matcher.group() = " + matcher.group());
    System.out.println("matcher.group(1) = " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("matcher.group(1) = " + matcher.group(2)); //xyz789
}
```

```java
private static String source() {
    String s = "{\"values\": [\n"
            + "        \"abc123\",        \"def456\",      "
            + "          \"xyz789\" ]\n"
            + "    }";

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Your solution should be based on a JSON Framework like Jackson or JAX-RS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Example with Jackson

It can be done almost effortlessly if you would use a library for parsing JSON, like Jackson, Gson, etc., instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Here's an example of how it can be done using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Assume you have the following POJO:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private List<String> values;
    
    // getters, setters
}
```

That's all you need to deserialize the incoming JSON:

```
String jsonStr = // incoming JSON

ObjectMapper mapper = new JsonMapper();
        
MyPojo pojo = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyPojo.class);
System.out.println(pojo.getValues());
```

*Output:*

```
[abc123, def456, xyz789]
```

More over, if you would use platforms like Spring, or Jakarta EE conversion of requests and responses would be done automatically for you.

If the data is dynamic and introducing a POJO doesn't make much sense, then you can parse it as a Tree, and work with Nodes of that Tree:

```
String jsonStr = // incoming JSON
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new JsonMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonStr).get("values");
List<String> values = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {}).readValue(node);

values.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
abc123
def456
xyz789
```

## Parsing Manually

If you want to do it manually at all costs, here is a way to extract these values by capturing the JSON-array and splitting it:

```
String jsonStr = // incoming JSON
        
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("\"values\"\\s*:\\s*\\[(.+)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern1.matcher(jsonStr);
        
List<String> values = List.of();
        
if (matcher.find()) {
    values = Arrays.stream(matcher.group(1).split(","))
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\"", "").strip())
        .toList();
}
        
values.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
abc123
def456
xyz789
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, I've used this pattern to extract an array entry: `\"values\"\s*:\s*\[([\s\n\"\w\,]*)\]`

Comment: @dykovo You are welcome, by the way a closing square bracket `]` doesn't need to be escaped, it required only for opening bracket `\[`.